# Return Value From Asynchronous Web Service Call

Tags: vb.net, web-services, asynchronous, asmx, return-value

I'm using ASMX web services in VB.Net in VS 2005.  I am calling a function method on the web service that returns a true or false value.  This works fine if I call the the web method synchronously, but if I want to call the method asynchronously, the function returns to a sub and there is no return value; therefore, I can't tell whether the result of call is true or false.  Is there a way to make an asynchronous call and still get the true or false result (perhaps using the userState Object)?

For Example:

```
Dim MyResult as Boolean = MyService.GetResult(10)
Dim MyResult as Boolean = MyServer.GetResultAsync(10)
```

This doesn't work the compiler complains: "Expression Does Not Produce a Value"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say what kind of application you're using, but take a look at [How to: Implement an Event-Driven Asynchronous Web Service Client Using ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms230194%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: FYI, I'm calling the web service from a WinForms apps, not ASP.Net.

Comment: Then look at the previous article before the one on ASP.NET.

Comment: Thanks John, just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

In the proxy class that VS creates for you must exists something looking like BeginGetResult - this method returns interface IAsyncResult - with help of them you can detect when execution done. After it you will get a value.

Comment: `Begin*/End*` are no longer necessary in his situation, with the new event-driven model introduced in .NET 2.0.